# PHP: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I get the following error message: `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in <file location>`

The code:

```
$obj = new MySQLi();
$mysqli = $obj->connect();

/* Create a prepared statement */
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare(...)) { <--- error line
    ....more code
}

class MySQLi {
    public $mysqli;

    public function connect() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'icu');

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
            exit();
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($this->mysqli, "utf8");
        return $this->mysqli;
    }

    public function con_close(){
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$obj->connect` does not return a `mysqli` object (most likely due to a connection fail). `var_dump($mysqli)` would've told you this.

Comment: @vascowhite those threads did not help me, I have looked around.

Comment: @KarlMorrison do `var_dump($mysqli)`. What is the result? as h2o said

Comment: @h2ooooooo correct! You just got me on the right path now! Why is it returning null? I tried a connection outside of a class and it works (so I know the connection works)

Comment: @KarlMorrison What class are you using? [There's a MySQLi class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), but it has no `connect` method? You specify that in the constructor (`new mysqli(...options...)`). I can imagine that this might be a bit of a problem (specially for compatibility and portability)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I feel incredibly retarded right now. You are indeed correct, there is already a class which does this for me, I was treating mysqli as mysql hence creation of my custom class. If you answer the question I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) class does not have a `->connect()` method, and you might be working with a duplicate class name which is never a good idea (this is also the reason you're getting `NULL` and can't call the `prepare` method).

In the MySQLi class you start a connection in the [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password', 'the_database');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need an instance of mysqli:

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'icu');
   ```
2. You have spaces here `->`:

   ```
   if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare(...))....
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...))...
   ```

Comment: Fixed but unforunetly the same error resides :(